# How to use a function that returns another function?

Tags: javascript

There's something I'm fundamentally not understanding about how functions that return other functions work.  I have the following throttle function that I'm using to make sure a command doesn't get sent too often.  It's lifted entirely from StackOverflow already, I didn't write this.

```
// Returns a function, that, when invoked, will only be triggered at most once
// during a given window of time. Normally, the throttled function will run
// as much as it can, without ever going more than once per `wait` duration;
// but if you'd like to disable the execution on the leading edge, pass
// `{leading: false}`. To disable execution on the trailing edge, ditto.
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
    var context, args, result;
    var timeout = null;
    var previous = 0;
    if (!options) options = {};
    var later = function () {
        previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
        timeout = null;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    };
    return function () {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
        var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
            if (timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
            }
            previous = now;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            if (!timeout) context = args = null;
        } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

I'm tying it to a range slider.  This super basic interpretation works perfectly

```
volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.oninput = throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100);

function sendVolumeMessage() {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}
```

The problem is that I want to also do NON-Throttled things with that slider.  The following doesn't work

```
volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.oninput = setVolume();

function setVolume() {
    return function () {
        console.log(`Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
        throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100);
    }
}

function sendVolumeMessage() {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}
```

The console log shows "Volume 30" or whatever the number is, but it doesn't show the Throttled Volume.  What am I not understanding about how passing functions inside of functions works?  Clearly I'm not actually calling the throttle function inside my setVolume function, but I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: `oninput` seems to be the problem here. It can only accept one handler. If you try to add another one, the previous one is thrown away.

Comment: There is only one such assignment in the code though.

Comment: Yeah my first attempt at this was to just use two oninput handlers and I discovered what you're talking about.  That's when I started trying to have a single handler that called the throttle function and the nonthrottled function.

I didn't consider just using addEventListener instead of oninput, I suppose that would've worked as well.  I think I'm happier with it as written by CherryDT though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `throttle` function *returns* a new function but your code never uses that returned function. With that in mind, it works as follows:

```js
const throttledSendVolumeMessage = throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100); // get throttled version of function *once*

volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.oninput = setVolume();

function setVolume() {
    return function () {
        console.log(`Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
        throttledSendVolumeMessage(); // call the saved throttled version of the function
    }
}

function sendVolumeMessage() {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}
```

(Note: it's important to store the throttled function outside of the scope of the inner function so that it will call `throttle` only once. Otherwise, it would create a new *individually throttled* version of the function each time which would have no effect because each of those versions would get called once and thrown away so no actual throttling would ever take place.)

However it's quite useless to wrap your `setVolume` in another function, it could be simplified to:

```js
const throttledSendVolumeMessage = throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100); // get throttled version of function *once*

volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.oninput = setVolume; // no call here anymore

function setVolume() { // doesn't return another function
    console.log(`Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
    throttledSendVolumeMessage(); // call the saved throttled version of the function
}

function sendVolumeMessage() {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}
```

But we could actually do away with all those named functions which are then even getting referenced *above* their definition, and shorten the code to this:

```js
const volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol"); 

const throttledSendVolumeMessage = throttle(function () {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}, 100);

volSlider.oninput = function () {
    console.log(`Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
    throttledSendVolumeMessage();
};
```

And finally you could do away with the dependency on the `volSlider` variable in the outer scope:

```js
const throttledSendVolumeMessage = throttle(function (volSlider) {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}, 100);

document.querySelector("#slider-vol").oninput = function () {
    console.log(`Volume ${this.value}`);
    throttledSendVolumeMessage(this);
};
```

---

On a side note, although this isn't influencing your current problem: it is usually preferred to use `element.addEventListener('xyz', handler)` over `element.onxyz = handler` because the latter allows only one handler to be assigned (and a new assignment would replace the previous one), so it can cause unexpected problems later on if you (or some badly written third-party code) try to attach a second listener to the same event to do something else.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer.  I've got it working now with your and epascarello's answer and now I'm digging into the rest of your suggestions to clean it up more.

Answer (score 1):

Store throttle and call it

```
volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.oninput = setVolume();

function setVolume() {
    const fnc = throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100);
    return function () {
        console.log(`Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
        fnc();
    }
}

function sendVolumeMessage() {
    console.log(`Throttled Volume ${volSlider.value}`);
}
```

or add two separate events using addEventListener

```
function otherFunction () {
  console.log(new Date());
}

volSlider = document.querySelector("#slider-vol");
volSlider.addEventListener('input', throttle(sendVolumeMessage, 100));
volSlider.addEventListener('input', otherFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was missing.  I didn't understand that I wasn't actually calling the throttle function, just defining it.